# Can java.sql.Date be forced to insert only years, months, days to an Oracle Date column

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I have the following entity class in Java

```
@Column(name = "DPST_DT")
private java.sql.Date depositDate;
```

and the corresponding column definition in Oracle is

```
DPST_DT           NOT NULL DATE
```

However when I insert data to table occasionally I see non zero hours, minutes, seconds as well. 
For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (DPST_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DPST_DTL_WIP
```

returns

```
2019-03-05 00:00:00
2019-11-12 17:10:02
```

Isn't java.sql.Date supposed to insert only dates while hours, minutes, seconds default to 0?
I know there is an option of converting java.sql.Date to java.util.Date and Use @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
but wanted to make sure there is no other option using java.sql.Date

Versions Used:
Oracle 12C,
JDK 1.8.0_121,
Spring Data Rest 1.5.7

Comment: What's the type of the column in the database? I bet it's not `java.sql.Date` but rather something like `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or similar. Can you check that?

Comment: @deHaar From what I've found `DATE` type on Oracle DB do store hours, minutes and seconds. At the same time in docs for `java.sql.Date` "To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated."

Comment: I would strongly suggest against the use of `java.sql.Date` in your entities. The hierarchy is broken by design (all of the java.sql date/time related classes extend `java.util.Date`!). I would either use the new `java.time` classes or the old `java.util.Date` with an `@Temporal(DATE)` to achieve consistent results.

Comment: @Amongalen: you are right the JDBC specification requires that the time part has to be set to 0 but Oracle decided to ignore that part of the specification.

Comment: I was going to recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date` anyway. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. On top of that I think that your problem will vanish automagically when instead you use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who spent time answering this question. It gave some very valuable insights for a noob like me. I am using Spring DATA JPA, which uses Hibernate beneath the hood. Unfortunately changing from java.sql.Date to java.util.Date would entail a significant regression exercise. So I have used the following pattern to convert a java.sql.Date to a LocalDate and back to java.sql.Date. I know it is not the most elegant solution but it seems to be stripping off the hours/ minutes/ days.

```
public void setDepositDate(Date depositDate) {
        this.depositDate = Date.valueOf(depositDate.toLocalDate());
}
```

As Basil rightly said, it is better to start with a better Date API than the old java.sql.Date or java.util.Date. 
Regards,

Comment: If in a situation where there’s no way to avoid the old and poorly designed `java.sql.Date` class, this answer shows a simple and effective way to leverage java.time for solving the problem you had. Other than that you are correct, in general mixing old and new classes is a bad idea, it’s better to stick to the modern ones when we can.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite complicated topic. IMHO Oracle intentionally changed this behavior in JDBC drivers 12c.

See Oracle Metalink note: Doc ID 1944845.1.

> The behavior of setDate() has changed starting with Oracle JDBC Driver
>   12.1.0.1. As result, time is inserted into DATE column if using setDate() method.
>
> From Oracle JDBC Driver 12.1.0.1 : the time is inserted as defined in
>   the variables. Oracle JDBC Driver 11.2.0.4 or earlier : the driver
>   sets the time to "00:00:00".
>
> The behavior from Oracle JDBC Driver 12.1.0.1 is correct because
>   Oracle DATE can store time(hours/minutes/seconds). And Oracle SQL DATE
>   stores time so it is logical that setDate() would store the time
>   component.

Solution:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into emp(empno, hiredate) values(1111, ?)");

Date cd = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(cd);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date d = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

ps.setDate(1, d);     
ps.execute();
```

OR:

> Set the oracle.jdbc.DateZeroTime property to true The property
>   oracle.jdbc.DateZeroTime is available from Oracle JDBC Driver version
>   12.2.0.1.

Somewhere on SO, there is also explanation from Oracle JDBC developers explaining what did they change and why.

I'd say that original ISO SQL idea to have separate datatype for DATE and to DAYTIME is unpractical. And Oracle's DATE datatype can store both since ever(it is older that ISO SQL). JDBC drivers used to be strict to standards, but now, since Oracle "controls" Java, they keep adding various fancy features.

PS: And when comes to TIMESTAMP (with timezone) in Java vs. in Oracle it gets even more complicated.

Comment: Both `Date` and `Calendar` are legacy types, poorly designed, terrible classes. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *jsva.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

## Legacy class `java.sql.Date`

The terrible `java.sql.Date` class pretends to represent a date-only but actually includes a time-of-day in UTC. This fact is likely the source of your trouble. Rather than explore further, I suggest you stop using that class.

> Isn't java.sql.Date supposed to insert only dates while hours, minutes, seconds default to 0?

Yes there is some kind of adjustment made in an attempt to zero out the time-of-day. But a time zone is involved in a way that was never clear to me. Again, rather than waste precious time on deciphering the behavior of an intrinsically flawed hack of a class, just use instead a modern *java.time* class instead.

## Oracle `DATE`

The [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) type in Oracle database is misnamed. This type represents a date and time-of-day in whole seconds without the context of a time zone.

Lacking a time zone or offset from UTC means the database type `Date` **cannot represent a moment**, is not a point on the timeline. The appropriate type in Java would be a `LocalDateTime` after truncating its nanoseconds to whole seconds.

Beware: This is the wrong type for tracking specific moments such as the moment when closing on the purchase of real estate, or the moment money was transferred. This type is only appropriate when:

- The date and time are meant to be applied to any/every time zone such as “Christmas begins at 00:00 in the 25th of December 2019”.
- When booking future appointments for a certain time of day (such as a dental appointment next January 23 at 3 PM in Chicago) regardless of politicians redefining the offset of the time zone (such as adopting, changing, or abandoning Daylight Saving Time DST) in which case we should separately be saving the intended time zone so we can later determine a moment using `ZonedDateTime` class when building a schedule. Be aware that politicians round the world have shown a proclivity for repeatedly tinkering with the offset of their juridictions.

## `LocalDate`

First start with the date you desire. Represent that as a date-only value using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

Or get today’s date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;  // Capture today’s date.
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Convert to a date with time of day, to match the semantics of the Oracle `Date` column. We will use the first moment of the day as the time-of-day. For `LocalDateTime`, that is always the time `00:00:00.0`. That would *not* always be zero time if we were tracking moments with `ZonedDateTime`, where anomalies such as Daylight Savings Time mean the day on some dates in some zones start at another time such as  01:00:00.0.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ld.atStartOfDay() ;  // Adjusts our date into a date-time, always using 00:00:00.0 as time-of-day. *Not* a moment as it lacks context of zone/offset. Has no precise meaning.
```

## JDBC 4.2

In JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database using `ResultSet::getObject`/`PreparedStatement::setObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setOject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

We should reliably see a time-of-day of 00:00:00.0. We have eliminated the mysterious problem seen in the Question.

Drop that time-of-day to get only the date portion. Extract a `LocalDate` from our `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract just the date portion, omitting time-of-day.
```

Caveat: I have never used the Oracle database. So I have not tested this code.